# IdentityUser how to verify old password?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I would like to be able to change the current user password only if he/she inputs the right old password, like this:

[image: Way of updating user password]

But I've been strugling to find here and elsewhere an elegant solution,
my **current** solution looks like this:

```
var oldPasswordHashed = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(appUser, model.OldPassword);
if (oldPasswordHashed == appUser.PasswordHash)
{
    var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(appUser, appUser.PasswordHash, model.NewPassword);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(EditUserViewModel.OldPassword), "Error at changing password, retry later.");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using [VerifyHashedPassword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher.verifyhashedpassword(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(System.String,System.String)). If you do it the way you are currently doing it, you probably won't get any matches, because the salt could be different.

Comment: Other than @JohnWu's note, I don't really see anything especially wrong with this implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ChangePasswordAsync()` method expects the old password ***not*** to be hashed.

Try this instead.

```
_userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(appUser, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
```

Comment: Oh, good to know I was wrong, I thought it expected the hashed version.

Comment: @Eugene probably a common mistake.  The parameter is called `currentPassword` and the docs don't specify that it expects an unhashed value.